# Django - Images won't upload after posting form

Tags: python, html, django

Changing the username or the email works but not the profile picture.

I added my profile app in "INSTALLED_APPS", set MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL and set urlspatterns :

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'home.apps.HomeConfig',
    'inscription.apps.InscriptionConfig',
    'profile.apps.ProfilConfig',
]
    
[...]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

[...]

urlpatterns = [
    path('profile/', p.profile, name='profile'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I linked the user to its profile, set the default image in `models.py` and registered the model in `admin.py`

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='profile_image')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}'s Profile"

[...]

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Profil
    
admin.site.register(Profil)
```

Then I created the profile modification form in forms.py :

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile
    
class ChangeUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(
        label = 'Username',
        min_length = 4,
        max_length = 150,
            initial=User.username,
        )
        email = forms.EmailField(
            label = 'Email',
            min_length = 4,
            max_length = 150,
        )
    
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email']
    
class ChangeProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.FileField(
        label = 'Profile form'
    )

class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ['image']
```

Then I used it in views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import ChangeUserForm, ChangeProfileForm

@login_required
def profil(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = ChangeUserForm(
            request.POST,
            instance=request.user
        )

        p_form = ChangeProfileForm(
            request.POST,
            request.FILES,
            instance=request.user.profil
        )

        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your profile was successfuly modified!')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        u_form = ChangeUserForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ChangeProfileForm()
    
    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form,
    }
    
    return render(request, 'profile/profils.html', context)
```

And finally, I created my profile page :

```
{% extends "home/index.html" %}
    
{% block title %}
Profil
{% endblock %}
    
{% block content %}
<div id='profil'>
    <img src='{{ user.profil.image.url }}'>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in u_form %}
            <p>
                {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
                {{ field }}<br>
            </p>
        {% endfor %}
        {% for field in p_form %}
            <p>
                {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
                {{ field }}<br>
            </p>
        {% endfor %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <p id="messages">{{message}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit">Enregistrer</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: add this attribute in form tag and try once.   enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add enctype when you are using files in HTML form.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```